# Swing - Allowing JButton to always stay on page when scrolling in application

Tags: java, swing, hover, jbutton, jlayeredpane

I have this application that I am working on, I have a JFrame that uses a BorderLayout. In the JFrame is a JPanel, the JPanel is using a MigLayout.I am trying to make a JButton stay on the bottom left hand side of the screen , achieving a similar effect as the "position:fixed" property in CSS.

Any tips on how I can achieve this effect by code?

Tried JLayeredPane code from a few other sources, but still doesn't work somehow.

```
private JPanel contentPane;

/**
 * Launch the application.
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            try {
                for (LookAndFeelInfo info : UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
                    if (info.getName().equals("Nimbus")) {
                        UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                        break;
                    }
                }
                MainFrame frame = new MainFrame();
                ForumMainPage panel = new ForumMainPage(frame);

                panel.setFocusable(true);
                panel.requestFocusInWindow();
                frame.add(jLabelOnJButton());
                frame.setContentPane(panel);
                frame.pack();


                frame.setVisible(true);


            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
}

/**
 * Create the frame.
 */
public MainFrame() {


    Toolkit tk = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit();
    Dimension dim = tk.getScreenSize();

    this.setSize(dim);
    this.setUndecorated(true);
    this.setExtendedState(Frame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);

    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    this.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    this.add(jLabelOnJButton(),BorderLayout.CENTER);

}
 private static JComponent jLabelOnJButton(){
        JLayeredPane layers = new JLayeredPane();

        JLabel label = new JLabel("label");
        JButton button = new JButton("button");

        label.setBounds(40, 20, 100, 50);
        button.setBounds(100, 20, 150, 75);

        layers.add(label, new Integer(200));
        layers.add(button, new Integer(100));

        return layers;
    }
   }
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You could add the button to the frames glass pane...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add the button to the frame's glass pane.  This takes a little bit of work to make happen, as you need to keep track of the scroll pane relative to the glass pane, but it should achieve the desired effect

[image: overlay button]

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.Point;
import java.awt.event.ComponentAdapter;
import java.awt.event.ComponentEvent;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileReader;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;

public class OverlayButton {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new OverlayButton();
    }

    public OverlayButton() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.add(new TestPane());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public class TestPane extends JPanel {

        private JScrollPane sp;
        private JButton btn;
        private JTextArea ta;

        private JPanel glassPane;

        public TestPane() {
            setLayout(new BorderLayout());
            btn = new JButton("Print");
            ta = new JTextArea(10, 20);

            BufferedReader br = null;
            try {
                br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(new File("Script.txt")));
                String text = null;
                while ((text = br.readLine()) != null) {
                    ta.append(text + "\n");
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } finally {
                try {
                    br.close();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                }
            }

            ta.setCaretPosition(0);
            sp = new JScrollPane(ta);
            glassPane = new JPanel() {

                @Override
                public void doLayout() {
                    Point p = sp.getLocation();
                    Dimension dim = sp.getSize();
                    p = SwingUtilities.convertPoint(sp, p, this);

                    btn.setSize(btn.getPreferredSize());
                    int barWidth = sp.getVerticalScrollBar().getWidth();
                    int barHeight = sp.getHorizontalScrollBar().getHeight();
                    int x = p.x + (dim.width - btn.getWidth()) - barWidth;
                    int y = p.y + (dim.height - btn.getHeight()) - barHeight;
                    btn.setLocation(x, y);
                }

            };
            glassPane.setOpaque(false);
            glassPane.add(btn);
            glassPane.addComponentListener(new ComponentAdapter() {

                @Override
                public void componentResized(ComponentEvent e) {
                    e.getComponent().doLayout();
                }

            });
            add(sp);
        }

        @Override
        public void addNotify() {
            super.addNotify();
            SwingUtilities.getRootPane(this).setGlassPane(glassPane);
            glassPane.setVisible(true);
            glassPane.revalidate();
        }

        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            return new Dimension(200, 200);
        }

        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g.create();
            g2d.dispose();
        }

    }

}
```

Take a look at [How to use Root Panes](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/rootpane.html) for more details

Comment: There are a couple of other hacks, but this the most general ;)

Answer (score 1):

Try using the OverlayLayout:

```
JPanel contentPane = new JPanel();
contentPane.setLayout( new OverlayLayout(ContentPane) );
frame.setContentPane( panel );

JButton button = new JButton(...);
button.setAlignmentX(0.0f);
button.setAlignmentY(1.0f);
contentPane.add( button );

ForumMainPage panel = new ForumMainPage(frame);
contentPane.add( panel );
```

Comment: a bar(just pure empty space) appears above my ForumMainPage Panel for some reason :(